# Apache Rewrite problems with my blog

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am having a hard time getting the rewrite rule setup correctly for my website&blog.  Here is the current line in Apache's virtual host:

```
RewriteRule ^/(?:blog|apc|_em|phpsecinfo|blog/)/ - [L]
```

I am able to access my URL at www.domainname.com/blog/
But I am unable to access it at www.domainname.com/blog  (without the ending /)

How can I edit my Rewrite rule so that I can reach the blog without the ending / ?  Thanks

Comment: I do have additional Rewrites which maybe I should show in case of conflicts:
RewriteRule ^/(?:blog|apc|_em|phpsecinfo|blog/)/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/crossdomain\.xml$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/google441bc299e6190ab5\.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/sitemap\.xml$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/favicon\.ico$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*_css.*\.css.*) /$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*_js.*\.js.*) /$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*_swf.*\.swf.*) /$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*_img.*\.[jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|bmp|BMP|png|PNG].*) /$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
RewriteRule ^/(blog|apc|_em|phpsecinfo)$ /$1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/(?:blog|apc|_em|phpsecinfo)/ - [L]
```

Comment: I made the change and I could no longer hit the blog with or without the "/".  I got this message in the browser, Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to anchor the end of the first rule.

Comment: Do I need the same "apc,phpsecinfo,etc" on both lines?  Or only on the first?

Comment: It depends on whether or not there are any rules after the second. If there are then the second line prevents those paths from being rewritten later.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **?** modifier to whatever slash you want to make optional:

```
RewriteRule ^/(?:blog|apc|_em|phpsecinfo)/? - [L]
```